# Bind UDP server on specific ip address ERLANG

Tags: udp, erlang, erlang-otp

I need to bind the UDP server to a specific IP address. Now I'm creating a UDP server like this

```
start_link(N,Param) ->
  gen_server:start_link({local,?SERVER},?MODULE, [N,Param], []).

%% ------------------------------------------------------------------
%% gen_server Function Definitions
%% ------------------------------------------------------------------

%% opens UDP listening socket. May be sockets will be more than 1
init([N,ListenPort]) ->
  Port=ListenPort+N-1,
  inets:start(),
  {ok,Socket}=gen_udp:open(Port,[{active,once},{reuseaddr,true},binary]),
  {ok, #state{port=Port,socket=Socket,in=0,out=0}}.
```

Where PARAM is UDP server port.
I don't know how to bind it to some IP.
Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ip` option, passing the address as a tuple:

```
{ok,Socket}=gen_udp:open(Port,[{active,once},{reuseaddr,true},binary,{ip,{127,0,0,1}}]),
```

If you have the IP address in string format, you can use [`inet:parse_address/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#parse_address-1) to parse it into a tuple:

```
{ok, IpAddress} = inet:parse_address("127.0.0.1"),
{ok,Socket}=gen_udp:open(Port,[{active,once},{reuseaddr,true},binary,{ip,IpAddress}]),
```